# How do I encapsulate data for an ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, adapter, encapsulation

I have a constructor from my custom adapter class within my activity:

```
CustomAdapter cAdapt = new CustomAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, newlist);
```

Currently, "newlist" is an `ArrayList<String>`. It is used for setting a `TextView` in my custom adapter with the data that it holds for each item in a list. Problem is that each item in my `ListView` holds three `TextView` and an `ImageView`.

How do I encapsulate the data for all 5 objects then pass it into my constructor?

Answer (score 1):

You can use BaseAdapter and create Custom listview. 
You have to create custom_list.xml file which contains your textviews and images.

```
itemlist.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(this));
```

Create class like this

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtDescription;
    TextView txtDate;
}

public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    // private static ArrayList<SearchResults> searchArrayList;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return arrayRSS.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrayRSS.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.txtDescription = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.description);
            holder.txtDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtTitle.setText(arrayRSS.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.txtDescription.setText(arrayRSS.get(position)
                .getDescription());
        holder.txtDate.setText(arrayRSS.get(position).getPubdate());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 for following best practices from the Google IO talk (using a Holder and tag) and re-using convertView.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an object `ItemInfo` and includes each of the five fields of data with getters and setters.  Then make an `ArrayList<ItemInfo>`, and pass it on to your adapter and handle it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the arraylist as

```
   ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> arraylist=new ArraList<ArrayList<Object>>
```

where ArrayList contains data for three textview and one imageview..